# Need code to be able to Check through current column and another column, and Match to use the same order number

Tags: excel, vba

if you see below, I have 3 columns, all i basically want is to check column A and Column B, if the carrier (Column A) and Date (Column B) are equal then it will have the same Order Number.

For example: In this case, A3 = A6 and B3 = B6 , so it should have the same order number as one above (160) not 163. I hope this makes it clear.

[image]

Thanks for the help. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite interesting, so I went ahead and wrote some code. Copy this into a new module and change the sheetname etc. to fit to your workbook. You may also need to redefine `fr` (firstrow, currently set to 2). The code also currently marks all the changed order-numbers red with the line `.Range("C" & r).Font.ColorIndex = 3`. Delete / comment it, if you don't want that.

```
Sub matching()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tws As Worksheet

Dim keys() As String
Dim tmpKey As String
Dim pos As Integer

Dim fr, lr As Integer           'first row, last row of data


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set tws = wb.Worksheets("Vigmo")

    fr = 2

    lr = tws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row


    ReDim keys(1 To lr - 1)

    With tws
        keys(1) = .Range("A" & fr).Value & "_" & .Range("B" & fr).Value
    End With

    For r = fr + 1 To lr

        With tws

            tmpKey = .Range("A" & r).Value & "_" & .Range("B" & r).Value

            If UBound(Filter(keys, tmpKey)) >= 0 And tmpKey <> "_" Then
                'found in array -> replace orderNumber
                'On Error resume next
                pos = Application.Match(tmpKey, keys, 0)
                'On Error goto 0

                .Range("C" & r).Value = .Range("C" & pos + 1).Value
                .Range("C" & r).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                'not found -> next
            End If

            keys(r - 1) = tmpKey


        End With

    Next r


End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions as to how this code works!

Comment: For some reason i am getting an error at this step 
`pos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tmpKey, keys, 0)`

Comment: why do you have `Application.worksheetfunction`? Try only `Application.Match`

Comment: I have added two lines to the code above, does it work now? Application.Match throws an error if it does not find any matches. I thought I had eliminated that possibility with the if-clause around it. Maybe not...

Comment: I was literally about to try On Error, works like a charm after that ! thanks a lot mate!! absolute genius you are :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have empty rows in your data?

Comment: It is indeed. I changed the code slightly to account for that, just for the sake of correctness :D `On Error` should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code that I came up with that does what your looking for. I dont know how you are generating your order numbers but I assumed they are already present. Hope this helps you :)

```
Sub OrderNumber()

Dim SearchTerm As String
Dim DateTerm As Date
Dim NumberOfEntries As Long
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1") '<==== Sets the workbook. change it to what yours is called

NumberOfEntries = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("A:A")) '<=== Find the number of entries

For x = 2 To NumberOfEntries '<==== Goes through all the entries
    SearchTerm = wks.Cells(x, 1) '<===== The Search term (Carrier)
    DateTerm = CDate(wks.Cells(x, 2)) '<==== The search Date
    For y = x To NumberOfEntries '<===== goes through everything below the search term to speed things up
        If wks.Cells(y, 1) = SearchTerm And CDate(wks.Cells(y, 2)) = DateTerm Then '<=== If the name and the date match then
            wks.Cells(y, 3) = wks.Cells(x, 3) '<==== Copy the order number
        End If
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Just put this in a module or wherever you want but I made it in a module.

G

Comment: I did try this method and it does work! thanks a lot for the solution mate, I am going to mark Sun's as the answer as he responded first. Sorry ! and thanks!